# How to get particular date format in Hijri in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, hijri

I want to get date in hijri calender in below format

```
1/جماد الأول/ 1438
```

but i don;t how can mix these locales.I tried setting the locale but it does not give me 1/1438.I am using below code.

```
NSCalendar * hijri = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierIslamicCivil];
NSDateFormatter * formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSLocale *locale  = [[NSLocale alloc]initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"ar_SA"];
[formatter setLocale:locale];
[formatter setCalendar:hijri];
dateString =[formatter stringFromDate:date];
```

Please tell how can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong is your code, you need to add one more attribute in `NSDateFormatter`.

Add below line in your code:

```
[formatter setDateFormat:@"dd/yyyy"];
```

*Set your desire date format in above line*

Final code will be:

```
NSCalendar * hijri = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierIslamic];
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSLocale *locale  = [[NSLocale alloc]initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"ar_SA"];
[formatter setLocale:locale];
[formatter setCalendar:hijri];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"dd/yyyy"];
NSString *dateString =[formatter stringFromDate:date];
NSLog(@" dateString :%@", dateString);
```

Comment: Please read the date i want.Your code will only give hijri date.